# Nesting quotes in JavaScript/HTML

Tags: javascript, html, quotes

How do you nest quotes in HTML beyond the second level? As far as I know, there are only 2 types of quotes - single(') and double("). I am aware of escaping using slashes - you have to escape in the code but that escaping won't work at the browser level. What is the accepted method to get around something like the following?

```
<p onclick="exampleFunc('<div id="divId"></div>');">Some Text</p>
```

That code prints to the browser:

> ');">Some Text

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You need to use proper escaping/encoding. Either in HTML using character references:

```
<p onclick="exampleFunc('&lt;div id=&quot;divId&quot;&gt;&lt;/div&gt;');">Some Text</p>
```

Or in JavaScript using string escape sequences:

```
<p onclick="exampleFunc('\x3Cdiv\x20id\x3D\x22divId\x22\x3E\x3C/div\x3E');">Some Text</p>
```

Comment: I'm not clear as to when one should pick the first versus the second.  I tried the first in an alert (e.g. `alert("&quot;")`), and got an error suggesting that "&quot;" was being treated as an actual quote, but the second form worked.

Answer (score 3):

Edit: this is not a solution for JavaScript in HTML, but for JavaScript only. My bad...

```
eval('eval(\"eval(\\\"alert(\\\\\\\"Now I\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'m confused!\\\\\\\")\\\")\")');
```

[Link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_quotation#In_JavaScript_programming). It's "recursive escaping".

Comment: As a layman pretending to be a programmer, I'll just say, I'm not doing this.

Answer (score 0):

```js
    const _advanceEscapeCount = (escapeCount, level) => {
      const linearPosition = Math.log(escapeCount + 1) / Math.log(2);
      return Math.pow(2, (linearPosition + level)) - 1;
    };

    const deepNestQuotes = (str, level) => {
      for (let i = str.length - 1; i >=0 ; i--) {

        if (str[i] === '"') {

          const index = i;
          let count = 0;
          while (str[i - 1] === '\\') {
            count++;
            i--;
          }

          const firstPart = str.substr(0,index - count);
          const lastPart = str.substr(index,str.length);

          const escapedCount = _advanceEscapeCount(count, level);
          str = firstPart +  '\\'.repeat(escapedCount) + lastPart;
          //str = firstPart +  escapedCount + lastPart;
        }
      }

      return str;
    };



    deepNestQuotes("1st-level-begin \"2nd-begin   \\\"3rd-begin  \\\\\\\"4th level\\\\\\\"   3rd-end\\\"   2nd-end\" 1st-level-end", 1);

    deepNestQuotes("1st-level-begin \"2nd-begin   \\\"3rd-begin  \\\\\\\"4th level\\\\\\\"   3rd-end\\\"   2nd-end\" 1st-level-end", 2);
```

Answer (score -4):

you need to escape the characters using the \

so your code should look like

```
<p onclick="exampleFunc('<div id=\"divId\"></div>');">Some Text</p>
```

Here is some info on [Special Characters](http://www.c-point.com/javascript_tutorial/special_characters.htm)

Comment: No, that terminates the HTML attribute value as `exampleFunc('<div id=\`.