# Javascript html: Constructing a Quoted Google search String

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to construct a quoted google search string, and put this string in a link. The user would click on the link and be taken to the quoted search result. (Using JQuery)

```
$(".abstract_text",this).append('<div><a href="http://google.com/search?btnI=1&q="'+art_title.make_search()+'"> Search For Fulltext</a></div>');
```

The above code gives this output:

```
http://google.com/search?btnI=1&q=The+Q+switched+ND+YAG+laser+effectively+treats+tattoos+in+darkly+pigmented+skin
```

I would like to find a way to produce this output:

```
http://google.com/search?btnI=1&q="The+Q+switched+ND+YAG+laser+effectively+treats+tattoos+in+darkly+pigmented+skin"
```

My question seems to be related to this question but I'm not exactly sure how to apply the answer that was accepted there: [Nesting Quotes in JavaScript/HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3039765/nesting-quotes-in-javascript-html)

*Please Note that though the search results are the same regardless of the output in this case, they will be different in general.

**Solution:Use the encode URI function**

```
$(".abstract_text",this).append('<div><a href="http://google.com/search?btnI=1&q='+encodeURI('"'+art_title.make_search()+'"')+'"> Search For Fulltext</a></div>');
```

Output:

```
http://www.google.com/search?btnI=1&q=%22Early+treatment+of+traumatic+tattoo+by+erbium+YAG+laser%22
```

Comment: Add a jQuery tag if you're using jQuery. Otherwise, people will think this is a pure JS question.

Comment: Ok Matt, though in the end it did turn out to be a general problem not specifically related to jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about JQuery but I guess what you want to do is encode your URL's special chars.
You can use the native Javascript function `encodeURI()` [(function reference)](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURI.asp)

The default encoding for double quotes `"` is `%22`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".abstract_text", this).append('<div><a href=\'http://google.com/search?btnI=1&q=\"'+art_title.make_search()+'\"\'> Search For Fulltext</a></div>');
```

Comment: Doesn't work. The output is this: http://google.com/search?btnI=1&q= ...then nothing more. When I inspect the element with firebug the rest of the text has been turned into an attribute. <a skin+contraction+with+pulsed+co2+and+erbium+yag+laser="" href="http://google.com/search?btnI=1&amp;q="> Search For Fulltext</a> hmm ... intresting.

Comment: That is interesting.. Tried it on Chrome and it seems to work fine :P Ah well, encoding really is the correct way to go.

Comment: I was using firefox, just another obscure difference between the two I guess.