# Handling three types of quotes

Tags: html, string, jsp, quotes, double-quotes

I have a JSP File which also uses JavaScript for some operations.
To Display a filled textinput-field I use:

```
String s="theValue";
out.println("<input type='text' value='"+s+"' name='nameField' id='name' onchange=doSomething('str2','str1')/>");
```

But it won't work if I don't put the `doSomething(str1,str2)` under qoutes.

Am I forced to use three types of quotes?
Is there a different way to solve this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Nesting quotes in JavaScript/HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3039765/nesting-quotes-in-javascript-html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a JSP expert but can you not just escape the quotes like this?:

```
out.println("<input ... onchange=\"doSomething('str2','str1')\"/>");
```

Or alternatively switch your quotes round:

```
out.println('<input type="text" value="'+s+'" ... onchange="doSomething(\'str2\',\'str1\')"/>');
```

Or alternatively use templating and only output dynamic content where necessary and have the rest as standard HTML.

```
<input type="text" value="<%= s %>" onchange="doSomething('str1', 'str2)"/>
```