# sound does not play and console does not work

Tags: javascript, html, audio, console, console.log

I want to have different beep in my site but its doesnt work

```
<body>

<!-- html work-->

    <audio id="beep-07" src="../audio/beep-07.wav" autostart="false"></audio>
    <audio id="button-3" src="../audio/button-3.wav" autostart="false"></audio>
    <button onclick="playsound('beep-07')">beep-07</button> 
    <button onclick="playsound('button-3')">button-3</button> 

<!-- js work-->

<script>
    function playsound(name) {
        var sound = document.getElementById(name);
        sound.play();
        console.log(sound,name,"1");
    }
</script>

</body>
```

Does anyone know why it doesn't work as expected?
By the way, the console log also doesn't have any output!Does anyone know why?
**update**
Oh guys i'm so sry!the problem was a simple typo in the code!thanks for your help!i'm so sorry!

Comment: Any errors in the console? Buttons are in a form in your real code?

Comment: Yes,"uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'play' of null"

Comment: no there isn't i think you mean the problem mentioned in the other answer, if so, read my comment:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<button onclick="playsound('beep-07')">beep-07</button>
<button onclick="playsound('button-3')">button-3</button>
```

You can read about nesting quotation marks and apostrophes on this [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3039765/nesting-quotes-in-javascript-html).

Comment: It made no difference, what do you mean?you mean i should use ' instead of " ?are you sure there is a difference between them?

Comment: Oh yeah!i understood!but the thing is in my actual code the function is not called with a button, its called in another function with one single line:playsound("beep-07") so for me that isnt the problem:)thank you for your answer and sry for the mistake i will edit the question now;)

Comment: The difference is, writing `onclick="playsound("beep-07")"` ends the whole `onclick` too soon. The browser would interpret it as `playsound(` (from the frist `"` to the next `"` encountered), which is incorrect. If you don't use it like this, then this is not an issue, of course.

Answer (score 0):

```js
 function playsound(name) {
        var sound = document.getElementById(name);
        sound.play();
    }
```

```html
<audio id="beep-07" src="http://www.soundjay.com/button/beep-07.wav" autostart="false"></audio>
    <audio id="button-3" src="../audio/button-3.wav" autostart="false"></audio>
<button onclick="playsound('beep-07')">beep-07</button>
```

Try this:

```js
  function playSound () {
        document.getElementById('beep-07').play();
    }
```

```html
    <audio id="beep-07" src="http://www.soundjay.com/button/beep-07.wav"></audio>
    <button onclick="playSound()">beep-07</button>
```

Comment: Yeah, it works like that, i know!But i want to have different sound and one function:)

Comment: @aran:- As ROAL has said said, you can do it by simply changing the quotes. See the edited answer. It works

Answer (score 0):

Your code is absolutely ok,But went little wrong.
Try this

```
<button onclick="playsound('beep-07')">beep-07</button> 
<button onclick="playsound('button-3')">button-3</button>
```

Thank You