# How do I use quotes inside quotes

Tags: javascript, html

How to create ID in myFunction() , im using javascript file.
cuz javascript need single string for call html script in variable. cmiiw.

Sample code:

```
<button class="tablinks" onclick="openFolder(event, 'Folder1')">Folder 1</button>
```

Comment: Hi there, we need way more context to understand what you're asking for. Please provide example code and add more around what you're trying, what has failed and what you were expecting.

Comment: Please reframe from adding images of your code. Try using the code function in the editor to include it into your question so it wont be lost in the future

Comment: Sorry, the code does not appear in the post. i edit my code with image . '<button class="tablinks" onclick="openFolder(event, 'Folder1')">Folder 1</button>' +

Comment: I think it is 4 space tabs to allow the code to show up

Comment: I still have no idea what you're trying to do. Can you explain more?

Comment: What's wrong with the code you shared?

Comment: we need use string in variable javascript to call html script. i dont know how to call **Folder1** on function openFolder(event, 'Folder1') . because i use single string in button tag '<button></button>' +.

Comment: Still unclear? i need some help. 
https://prnt.sc/h6qyue

Comment: What are you trying to do?.Are you trying to create id on Html tag or are you trying to reference an ID on html when you click button so certain action is performed by JS.

Comment: '<button... onclick="openFolder(event, '+'"Folder1")">Folder 1</button>'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3039765/nesting-quotes-in-javascript-html

Comment: Thanks @GeorgeCampbell .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is more like:
How do I use quotes inside quotes. The solution is to use single quotes if you want double quotes in the string, and double quotes if you want single quotes in the string.

```
'<button class="tablinks" onclick="openFolder(event, '+'"Folder1")">Folder 1</button>'
```

alternatively use backticks; `template literals` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals
making the task much easier:

```
`<button class="tablinks" onclick="openFolder(event, 'Folder1')">Folder 1</button>`
```

Comment: Thanks, im newbie.